# How to understand string or array in the web service answer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray

I get to array value from web service. This array is 1 or more than 1-element array.If tempArra is 1 dimesional array and then  If I want to transfer the data in the array to another array(garbageDatesFor01) Then I get the error

```
EDIT: returning to the web service responses in 2 ways

RESPONSE 1

(
    (
    "2011-08-03",
    "2011-08-17"
    )
)

OR

RESPONSE 2
2011-08-04

NSArray *garbageDatesFor01=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempArr];

2011-08-26 18:43:35.689 AOK[1846:207] -[NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x990d8f0
2011-08-26 18:43:35.691 AOK[1846:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x990d8f0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x015d25a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01726313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x015d40bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01543966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01543522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x01535d87 -[NSArray initWithArray:] + 39
    6   TwenteMilieu                        0x0001323a -[ForgottenContainerT1 connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 3750
    7   Foundation                          0x00113112 -[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) sendDidFinishLoading] + 108
    8   Foundation                          0x0011306b _NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading + 133
    9   CFNetwork                           0x0117148e _ZN19URLConnectionClient23_clientDidFinishLoadingEPNS_26ClientConnectionEventQueueE + 220
    10  CFNetwork                           0x0123c6e1 _ZN19URLConnectionClient26ClientConnectionEventQueue33processAllEventsAndConsumePayloadEP20XConnectionEventInfoI12XClientEvent18XClientEventParamsEl + 293
    11  CFNetwork                           0x01167c80 _ZN19URLConnectionClient13processEventsEv + 100
    12  CFNetwork                           0x01167acf _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 251
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x015b38ff __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0151188b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 571
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x01510d86 __CFRunLoopRun + 470
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x01510840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x01510761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x01b411c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x01b41289 GSEventRun + 115
    20  UIKit                               0x0037fc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  TwenteMilieu                        0x00002644 main + 102
    22  TwenteMilieu                        0x000025d5 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important line is :

```
2011-08-26 18:43:35.689 TwenteMilieu[1846:207] -[NSCFString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x990d8f0
```

It means you are calling `count` on a string.  The object you think is an array is actually a string.

From looking at your code, `tempArr` could be either an array or a string.  Try this:

```
if ([tempArr isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
{
    // Handle array case
}
else if ([tempArr isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
    // Handle string case
}
```

It's probably a good idea to change the name of `tempArr` to something else, like `tempResponse` or similar.

Comment: I updated to question. I did not to resolution for this problem help me